# How can I use eager loaded data after join for each record returned?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

In my code I join 2 models (e.g. Post and Comment) then I eager load a third model (e.g. Author). When I print each record **rails uses the eager loaded model data for the first instance of Post but triggers additional database queries for each additional instance of Post**. This is a bit of an n+1 problem.

What I do not understand is why I'm only able to use the eager loaded data for the first record of each post and not the additional records returned by the join?

I have looked at similar questions and do not feel these address the exact same issue. These include:

- [why is this rails association loading individually after an eager load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110967/why-is-this-rails-association-loading-individually-after-an-eager-load)
- [belongs_to association loaded individually even after eager loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451312/belongs-to-association-loaded-individually-even-after-eager-loading)
- [Eager loading not loading in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240955/eager-loading-not-loading-in-rails), and others

I've also looked into the rails source code, specifically [ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb) and have tried to modify it a bit locally to see if I could narrow down where the issue is or if it happens here. I had thought that possibly this class was stripping out non-unique record instances by id (which I think it is at line 92) but when I change this my issue is not resolved.

I did stumble across this [whacky edge case](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AssociationPreload/ClassMethods/preload_associations#386-Whacky-edge-case) which seemed applicable but in my actual code I'm using `find_by_sql` and have not been able to implement this effectively.

I have created a **[gist with steps to reproduce the issue](https://gist.github.com/boykoc/6514cd4773ebdd9ad49195bc34768453)** I'm experiencing and the output I'm getting. Any help would be appreciated.

**Note: This example is the simplest setup I could think of that demonstrates the same issue I'm having in my actual code.** In my example case I know I could eager load the comments and authors however, in my actual code there is a much more complex join and the join is required. I would not be able to eager load the Comment model from this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that find this in the future, here is what I've found and what I implemented.

## Simple gist example

For the simple example outlined in my gist, I found that I can get the desired results be changing the following.

Gist:

```
# Triggers n+1 for author after first puts of an author.
posts = Post.joins(:comments).select("posts.*, comments.body").includes(:author)
posts.each do |x|
  puts "#{x.title} #{x.author.name} #{x.body}"
end
```

Changed to:

```
# Works as expected.
posts = Post.joins(:comments, :author).select("posts.*, comments.body").includes(:author)
posts.each do |x|
  puts "#{x.title} #{x.author.name} #{x.body}"
end
```

By joining the `author` I get the results I wanted without additional queries.

## More complex example and Implementation

Although the above solved my simple example I used to demonstrate my problem, in my more complex real-world problem (as noted in my question) I was not able to implement this additional join to solve things.

Instead I implemented the Query Object Pattern and Decorator Pattern as outlined in this great [Thoughbot post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/active-record-eager-loading-with-query-objects-and-decorators) and in the rails handbook on github ([Query Object Pattern](https://github.com/infinum/rails-handbook/blob/master/Design%20Patterns/Query%20Objects.md) and [Decorator Pattern](https://github.com/infinum/rails-handbook/blob/master/Design%20Patterns/Decorators.md)).

These patterns allowed me to get all the benefits of eager loading the specific associations I wanted but for my much more complex query.